# Responsive design mode doesn't show the right mobile experience

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've been designing a new cover for my book with HTML and CSS. after it was finished , I saw the result in Responsive design mode in both Firefox and Google Chrome but when I open the website on my phone with Chrome (which by the way is a Galaxy s3) , It's a totally different story.
here's my website's [link](https://ali-xoerex.github.io/)

I want it to be the same as what it is in Responsive Design Mode

this is my HTML and CSS file:

```css
@font-face{
  font-family: 'halogen';
  src: url(https://ali-xoerex.github.io/static/fonts/halogen.otf);
}

@keyframes iwoz{
  to{
    text-shadow: 1px 1px green;
    color: green;
  }
}

body{
  background: url(https://ali-xoerex.github.io/static/img/macos.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.item , #clock{
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.navigation{
  width: 100%;
  background:  rgba(109, 110, 112,0.3);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  height: auto;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.title{
  margin-top: 3%;
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header{
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-top: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  border-top-left-radius: 1%;
  border-top-right-radius: 1%;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to top,#ebebeb, #d5d5d5);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top,#ebebeb, #d5d5d5);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(to top,#ebebeb, #d5d5d5);
  background: linear-gradient(to top,#ebebeb, #d5d5d5);
}

.close{
  text-indent: -99999px;
  border: 1px solid #ff5c5c;
  background: #ff5c5c;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 9px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

.close:hover{text-indent: 0;}
.minimize:hover{text-indent: 0;}
.size:hover{text-indent: 0;}

.size{
  text-indent: -99999px;
  border: 1px solid #ffbd4c;
  background: #ffbd4c;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 9px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

.minimize{
  text-indent: -99999px;
  border: 1px solid  #00ca56;
  background:  #00ca56;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 9px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}

.h{
  margin-left: 45%;
}

.buttons{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center; 
  min-width: 55px;
}

.right{
  margin-right: 10px;
}


.content{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'halogen';
  font-size: 80px;
  animation: iwoz 2s forwards;
}

.window{
  border: 2px solid #ebebeb;
  background: rgba(109, 110, 112,0.3);
  border-radius: 1%;
  width: 800px;
  height: 70%;
  max-height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}

.main{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.icons{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.left{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-width: 85px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.dock{
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  border-top-left-radius: 2%;
  border-top-right-radius: 2%;
  background: rgba(109, 110, 112,0.8);
  left: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>IWoz Cover</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="static/css/index.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navigation">
      <div class="main">
          <div class="left">
              <div class="logo"><img src="https://ali-xoerex.github.io/static/img/apple.png" alt=""></div>
              <div class="item">IWoz</div>
          </div>
          <div id="clock" class="right">
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      <div class="window">
        <div class="header">
          <div class="buttons" style="display:flex;flex-direction:row">
            <div class="close">
              X
            </div>
            <div class="size">
                -
            </div>
            <div class="minimize">
                +
            </div>
          </div>  
          <div class="h">IWoz</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          IWoz
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dock">
      <div class="icons">
        <a href="https://github.com/Ali-Xoerex/Ali-Xoerex.github.io" role="button"><img src="https://ali-xoerex.github.io/static/img/github.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href="https://ali-xoerex.github.io/chapters/1/1.html" role="button"><img src="https://ali-xoerex.github.io/static/img/book.png" alt=""></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      function update_clock(){
        let days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat"]
        let date = new Date();
        let clock = date.toLocaleTimeString();
        document.getElementById('clock').innerText = days[date.getDay()]+' '+clock
      }
      setInterval(update_clock,1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be really appreaciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect the height of your body element, on which the background-image relies, it does not fully cover the whole screen. Just add height:100vh; to your body element.

Comment: Thank you so Much!

Comment: I recommend you to put the background on the html element instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't provide screenshots and concrete issues, I can only assume you refer to the background not reaching the bottom of the screen.

What you are seeing on the desktop browsers is not entirely correct behaviour. You put the background on `body` and since `div.navigation` and `div.dock` are positioned, its dimensions depend only on bounding `div.title`, which doesn't reach the bottom of the screen.

You can do the following:

1. Set `body` to `min-height: 100vh`. Now because of some margins you'll get a scrollbar.
2. Change `div.title` `margin-top: 3%` to `padding-top: 3%`
3. Change the default `margin` on `body` to `padding` - set `margin: 0` on `body` and add `padding: 8px` on body.